# Eclipse IDE creates only app_name(String) file in strings.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, homescreen, reinstall

When I make a New Android Application Project in Eclipse, in /res/values/strings.xml exists only the file app_name(String). hallo(String) is absent and the emulator displays only a home screen without the title of the blank application (it is the basically HalloWorld project).
Please, have you an idea where to look for the error?
I am trying to solve the problems step by step.
First of all I think it is important that I deleted the folder containing /eclipse, /sdk, SDK Manager.exe and I created a new folder with these items. There are more other problems. 
Can you recommend me a method to reinstall the ADT Bundle on Windows 7 64 bit? Do you think this could solve the problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It shouldn't happen. But does it work if you add a TextView to xml file, and `<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>` to strings.xml?

Comment: Just add "Hello" in between app_name string. Ex: <string name="app_name">Hello</string>